# use eval() in numba / NumbaLSODA?

Tags: python, eval, numba, ode

I'm trying to use NumbaLSODA to optimize my model, which is essentially solving an initial value ODE problem (can be quite stiff). My original model is based on scipy/solve_ivp which works perfectly fine, just a bit slow, even with Jacobian matrix provided. Couldn't think of any other way to optimize the callable derivative function anymore so I started looking for other options like NumbaLSODA.

I implemented NumbaLSODA and my derivative function looks something like this:

```
@cfunc(lsoda_sig)
def deriv(t,y,ydot,coeff):
    ydot[0] = <very long math expression>
    ydot[1] = <very long math expression>
    ydot[2] = <very long math expression>
    ...
```

where coeff is an array that is passed into deriv() as an arg. The math expressions may look something like this:

```
coeff[0]*y[0]*y[1] + coeff[1]*y[2] - coeff[2]*y[3] ...
```

Again this works great, and the model is considerably faster than the scipy/solve_ivp version, so very promising!

Here's one problem. The ydot array in the derivative function can be very long and complicated. Therefore in my scipy/solve_ivp-based model I had another snippet to generate a list of strings, compile, then eval inside the derivative function. It might be a bit slower than directly providing the ydot array, but drastically improves user-experience.

However, the eval() function does not seem to work in the NumbaLSODA-based model:

```
@cfunc(lsoda_sig)
def deriv(t,y,ydot,coeff):
    ydot[0] = eval(<very long math expression>)
    ydot[1] = eval(<very long math expression>)
    ydot[2] = eval(<very long math expression>)
    ...
```

and I end up with this error message:

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'eval': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```

I am not entirely familiar with numba. I wonder if there's a way to get eval() working

I am aware that some functions/operations would not work in numba. If this is indeed the case for eval(), is there a way to feed code-generated ydot array in the derivative function?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way an `eval` call can work *in a Numa function*.

`eval` is fundamentally incompatible with the way Numba works: it compile the code at runtime use tools like LLVM in order to get a binary code then executed (generally multiple times). To do that Numba require all variables and expressions (including function calls) to be strongly typed. Numba can use type inference to determine types mostly automatically but this is not possible to do that ahead-of-time with an `eval` function. Doing that at runtime, would be very inefficient as the function would need to be recompiled each time the content of the evaluated expression changes. It is actually even worse because the evaluated expression must be also parsed by the Python interpreted (a mandatory relatively-slow step required by Numba too). If the content of the evaluated expression is constant, then the need for `eval` is not justified. Using `eval` is generally seen as a bad practice and generally already innefficient in pure Python codes.

If using `eval` is mandatory in your case but the expression is often/always the same and it is independent of the function parameters, then there is a trick. You can generate and compile a whole set of Numba functions for the target expressions and store them in a cache to reuse them later. Put it shortly: *evaluate the code of the Numba functions themselves*.

Note that Numba is good only when compiled functions are quite intensive (typically a big loop). Otherwise, calling a Numba function is often slower than doing the work from the standard Python interpreter.

Comment: Thank you! The eval() isn't mendatory per se. It's just I haven't figured out a better way. I wrote a parser (since all math expressions are of similar format), which is faster than eval but slower than compile then eval. That's why I've been "abusing" eval. Could you elaborate on eval the numba function? I tried exec( '@cfunc(lsoda_sig) \ndef deriv(t,y,ydot,coeff) ...' ) and it does work, but it feels sloppy.

Comment: Yes I was thinking of such an `exec` call. If the expression are unique for all `deriv` calls, you can however generate the expression wrapped in a numba function (resulting in a big string) and `exec` it to generate a compiled numba function ahead of time. The numba functions can then be called in `deriv` like if they were classical functions. This help to make the `deriv` code cleaner. If there is multiples possible expressions, then you can cache them in a datastructure (eg. array or dict) but I am not sure Numba will like it.